# Copy cells with all properties

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
For I = 1 To ArchivoDestino.Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For J = 1 To 10
        Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(I, J) = ArchivoDestino.Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(I, J)
     Next J
Next I
```

As yo can see, I go until the cell, no any of its properties, but Excel only copy **.value**

Comment: This is what such a code line should do... Excel guesses that you try copying the value. Otherwise, you cannot copy everything **without using clipboard**... Or, to avoid clipboard, copy each property one by one: `Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(I, J).Interior.Color = ArchivoDestino.Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(I, J).Interior.Color`. And do so for all needed properties...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're after this:

```
Dim sourceRng As Range
    With ArchivoDestino.Worksheets("Agentes") 'reference your source worksheet
        Set sourceRng = .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), "J10") ' set a Range ranging from cell J10 to column A last not empty cell
    End With

        sourceRng.Copy Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(1, 1) ' copy the source range and paste to target position
```

a more condensed (and criptic) version of would be:

```
 With ArchivoDestino.Worksheets("Agentes") 'reference your source worksheet
    .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), "J10").Copy Worksheets("Agentes").Cells(1, 1)
 End With
```

BTW, all this can make sense if "Agentes" target sheet is not in the `ArchivoDestino` workbook